# Format tables in Google Colaboratory

Tags: google-colaboratory

The markdown syntax for creating tables does not draw any borders to table cells. How to achieve these stylings in a text cell:

- drawing borders
- alternate row colors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Styling markdown tables isn't currently supported.

Your best bet right now is to render your table as an output where you can control the rendering precisely.

Here's an example with borders and alternating colors:
https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=1oXkzlM0lPbDC8saNRUnkGOjpKCTiDHvM

Comment: Is there a way to hide the code cell and only show the output cell? I am using this tool to write a collaborative blog post with math equations.

Comment: This answer is outdated. Markdown tables are currently supported in Colab notebooks. See the [Colab Markdown Guide](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/markdown_guide.ipynb#scrollTo=Lhfnlq1Surtk) for a working example.